# How do I start Minecraft and Valorant from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, minecraft

Last night, I decided to try coding a batch file. I used some references and some online walkthroughs and ended up making the following program.

```
echo off
Title Log into CMD

:home
color 0A
echo ==================
echo.
echo [1] Log In
echo [2] Exit
set /p login=
if %login%==1 goto 1
if %login%==2 goto 2
goto error

:1
echo.
echo ==================
echo.
set and=if
set /p name=Enter your name: 
set /p pass=Enter your password: 
if %name%==Bob %and% %pass%==***** echo Welcome, Omid
if not %name%==Bob goto no
if not %pass%==***** goto no
goto GameMenu

:no
echo You're not Bob!
pause
echo Goodbye!
pause
exit

:2
exit

:error
echo You have to select a valid option!

:GameMenu
Title Game Menu
echo.
echo ==================
echo.
echo [1] Minecraft
echo [2] krunker.io
echo [3] Valorant
set /p gc=Enter the number of the game you would like to play:
if %gc%==1 goto Minecraft
if %gc%==2 goto krunker
if%gc%==3 goto Valorant
goto error

:Minecraft
start MinecraftLauncher.exe
exit

:krunker
start https://www.krunker.io/
exit

:Valorant
start RiotClientServices.exe
exit
```

This program is a simple one that you log into with a username and password, which then leads to a directory of games to open. The krunker.io works, but I wasn't sure on how to call Minecraft and Valorant. The processes that open up the games are what I called. For example, MinecraftLauncher.exe is the name of the process that would launch Minecraft. When I choose Minecraft from the menu, it gives the error message 'Windows cannot find "MinecraftLauncher.exe" Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.` This is strange given this is the literal name of the launcher. I was wondering if anyone with a bit more experience could help me out.

Comment: Why would Windows magically know what folder MinecraftLauncher.exe is located in? You have to tell it.

Comment: How do I do so @SomethingDark

Comment: Use the full path to the launcher and wrap it in quotes if there are spaces at any point. It's going to be something like `"C:\Program Files\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe"` or wherever you have it installed.

Comment: Ohhhh I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: When I use `start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe"` all it does is open a command prompt window called that. @SomethingDark

Comment: Right; `start` considers the first set of quotes it encounters to be the title of the window, so add either a title for the window or just a set of blank quotes.

Comment: Just bear in mind however, that you're starting a launcher, then immediately starting other processes. Whilst you're doing that your launcher may still be trying to get MineCraft up and running. It may therefore be necessary to add a delay, to ensure that everything is launched first. You can add a delay by using the timeout command. Open up a Command Prompt window, type `timeout /?`, press the 'ENTER' key, and read its usage information, to learn how to do that.

Comment: consider using the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command instead of `set /p`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go thru the path to initialize the application. Here's a step-by-step:

```
cd/
cd "Program Files (x86)/Minecraft"
start MinecraftLauncher.exe
```

You have to ensure that cmd is at `c:\` using `cd/`, then go to launcher file location and starts it. You can do that by using `start/d`.
So, here's your code:

```
@echo off
Title Log into CMD

:home
color 0A
echo ==================
echo.
echo [1] Log In
echo [2] Exit
set /p login=
if %login%==1 goto 1
if %login%==2 goto 2
goto error

:1
echo.
echo ==================
echo.
set and=if
set /p name=Enter your name: 
set /p pass=Enter your password: 
if %name%==Bob %and% %pass%==***** echo Welcome, Omid
if not %name%==Bob goto no
if not %pass%==***** goto no
goto GameMenu

:no
echo You're not Bob!
pause
echo Goodbye!
pause
exit

:2
exit

:error
echo You have to select a valid option!

:GameMenu
Title Game Menu
echo.
echo ==================
echo.
echo [1] Minecraft
echo [2] krunker.io
echo [3] Valorant
set /p gc=Enter the number of the game you would like to play:
if %gc%==1 goto Minecraft
if %gc%==2 goto krunker
if%gc%==3 goto Valorant
goto error

:Minecraft
cd/
start/d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft" MinecraftLauncher.exe
exit

:krunker
start https://www.krunker.io/
exit

:Valorant
cd/
start/d "C:\Program Files (x86)\*VALORANT LAUNCHER FOLDER*" RiotClientServices.exe
exit
```

And your login system is broken. If you put any key other than 1 or 2, you go direct to `:GameMenu`, it can be easily solved by  putting `:error` at the very end of the file or using a `goto home` before `echo You have to select a valid option!`
Hope this helps you.